# Estimate dimension of fibers for a morphism of schemes under 'very' weak assumpions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be an arbitrary dominant morphism of locally noetherian schemes over any field $k$. Assume that $X,Y$ are also *irreducible* with dimensions $\operatorname{X}=n $ and $ \operatorname{Y}=m$. We *don't* make any additional assumptions (like smoothness, flatness etc. )

Is there any result known generically estimating the dimension of fibers of $f$. Generically means here that I'm seeking for a result like 'there exist an open subscheme $U \subset Y$' such that
for all $y \in U$ the the dimension of the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is $\le n-m$?

I know there are some known results if we impose additional assumptions on (generical) flatness but here I would like to discuss the case if we not use such assumpions. Is there moreover any dependence on the base field $k$ known?

Comment: Qing Liu, *Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves*, Theorem 4.2.12 (not sure about last number), suggests that nonempty fibers always have dimension at least $n-m$.

Comment: I have searched the complete Liu's book including 4.2 (deals on
regular rings) but haven't 
found any result of your estimation $\le n-m$. The 4.2.2
is a corollary discussing when for a regular local ring $A$ the
quotient $A/f$ is regular too. In 4.3 the flat case is discussed,
as I remarked that case is to specific for me. 
Could check which theorem you mean which implies the
$\le n-m$ estimation when you have more time? That seems 
to be exactly that kind of extimation what I'm looking for but
I can't find it :( sorry, I would very thankful if you could borrow
some time to find it

Comment: what if restrict to discuss the dimension only of fibers over open $U \subset Y$?

Comment: I was thinking of 4.3.12 and the following corollary, but it’s possible I’m mistaken and the application of 4.3.12 isn’t straightforward.

Comment: Well, if $f: X \to Y$ is flat, then as Corollary 4.3.14 states
we get what we want. Theorem 4.3.12 is just a inequality
between stalks 

$\dim \ O_{X_y, x} \ge \dim \ O_{X, x} - \dim \ O_{Y, y}$


And I think that under general assumtions 
it's wrong (eg blow up a single point) that the dimension of the fiber is $\ge n-m$.
If we assume $X,Y$ affine say with $X= Spec \ A$ then $A_p=
codim(V(p), X)$ (prop 2.5.8 from same book)
for prime $p \subset A$, roghly
$\dim \ O_{X, x} \le \dim \ X$ and the difference
$\dim \ X- \dim \ O_{X, x}$ is in general

Comment: not related
to $\dim \ Y- \dim \ O_{Y, y}$ or $\dim \ X_y- \dim \ O_{X_y, x}$.
So it strongly depends on
special choice of points $x$ and $y=f(x)$ and I'm not sure
how it can be 'repaired'